# Azure web Node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I have created a node js website using azure node js template 
the app uses express and socket io

This is the server code
I have written a simple server side code with logs for each function

my server side code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
////Creating Server
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
//For Socket IO
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var port = process.env.port || 1337
server.listen(port);
var connections = [];
console.log('Server Running....');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

socket.on('subscribe', function (room) {
    //It's not logging this
    console.log('Connections: ', connections.length, ' Room: ', room);
    socket.join(room);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets still connected',       connections.length);  
});

socket.on('send message', function (data) {
    console.log('Message.', data.message);
      //this works fine when i comment the 'subscribe' function
      io.sockets.emit('new message', { msg: data.message, room: data.room});

   //I want this to work
     io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('new message', { msg: data.message, room: data.room });
});
});


});
```

From the client 
I connect to the website and use a emit to connect to the particular room

Client Side Code:

```
//Inside document.ready i am calling this

var socket = io.connect('http://example.azurewebsites.net'); //url
socket.emit('subscribe', 1);//Hardcoded
 $('#send').click(function (e) { // Send Button
     socket.emit('send message', {
            room: 1,
            message: $('#message').val() // Input Box Value
        });
 });
 socket.on('new message', function (data) {
    console.log('Message :',data.message,'Room :',data.room);
 });
```

The problem I am facing is the 'subscribe' function not working,
I get no logs for it.

What could be the reason

Comment: Are you calling `socket.emit('subscribe')` immediately on the client or after you're connected? When you say `send message` and `new message` work fine, can you clarify. In the example they'll be fired when they get that message from the server, but in the server example, `send message` is being received from the client. Also, in the `emit` call to `new message`, you've an extra `,` at the end of your data object, which is probably why the next call doesn't work

Comment: yes i am calling 'subscribe' immediately on the client side.The send message I have a input box and a button to send which on click sends the message and the console.log in the server side logs the message and the , I changed but still the io.sockets.in[room] doesn't work because the subscribe function doesn't seem to work

Comment: I get a log for connected, a log if i send a message, and the new message as of now just logging in the client side to see weather the message comes back

Comment: "yes i am calling 'subscribe' immediately on the client side" -> `emit` won't actually do anything on the client until you're connected; would that be it? I'll be home in a few hours, so if you don't get it fixed by then, I'll set up a reproduction. Can you post your client side code please?

Comment: added Client side code, sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I took your code and made a new project to test.

Server:

```
var app = require( 'express' )()
var http = require( 'http' ).createServer( app );
var io = require( 'socket.io' )(http);

// serve our main page
app.get( '/', function( req, res ){
    res.sendFile( __dirname + '/index.html' );
});

// called when socket.io gets an incoming connection
io.on( 'connection', function( socket ){

    console.log( "Socket " + socket.id + " connected" );

    // called when we disconnect
    socket.on( 'disconnect', function(){
        console.log( "Socket " + socket.id + " disconnected" );
    })

    // subscribe to a room
    socket.on( 'subscribe', function( room ){
        console.log( "Socket " + socket.id + " is connecting to room " + room );
        socket.join( room );
    })

    // called when the socket sends a message
    socket.on( 'send message', function( data ){
        console.log( "Message from " + socket.id + ": " + data.message );

        io.emit( 'new message', { msg: data.message, room: data.room } );
        io.in( data.room ).emit( 'new message', { msg: '[Room' + data.room + '] ' + data.message, room:data.room } );
    })
})

// start our server
http.listen( 3000, function() {
    console.log( 'Listening on *:3000' );
})
```

Client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Socket.IO test</title>
        <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();

            // listen for new messages
            socket.on( 'new message', function( data ){
                console.log( "Received message", data );
            })

            // subscribe to our room
            socket.emit( 'subscribe', 1 );

            // send our message
            socket.emit( 'send message', {
                room: 1,
                message: "Hello world"
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Aside from small stylistic differences (calling `io.sockets` is redundant, I just made the client calls directly rather than through a form, and I removed the `connections` array code and isn't not relevant to the problem), it's the same thing.

This is working for me locally.

As you're connecting to an external site, if you're not getting a log for the `subscribe` event, I'd suggest it's because you're calling `subscribe` before your client socket is finished connected.

The client has a `connect` event that you can listen to and move the `subscribe` call inside the callback. So your client code now becomes this:

```
var socket = io();

// listen for new messages
socket.on( 'new message', function( data ){
    console.log( "Received message", data );
})

// called when we're connected
socket.on( 'connect', function() {

    // subscribe to our room
    socket.emit( 'subscribe', 1 );

    // send our message
    socket.emit( 'send message', {
        room: 1,
        message: "Hello world"
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out